# R ggplot heatmap using geom_tile(): how to sort by year and show all years in y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After studying Hadley's book and searching here on SO I have created a heatmap consisting of a matrix of years and months, with the colour varying according the percentage change in a time series variable. The heatmap and the code I used to get it are shown below. I have a few remaining questions that I haven't been able to resolve on my own.

1) How can I sort/order the matrix so that the years in the y-axis run from the earliest to the latest? In this case I want the years to start from the top at 1995 and continue to 2011 at the bottom of the y-axis.

2) I want every year to be shown on the y-axis but instead it is showing only every 5th year. I thought that the scale_y_date in my code would deal with this but it seems to have no affect. How can I force the y-axis to display each year?

3) I suspect this is still on the ggplot2 "to do" list, but is there any way to make the x-axis labels (in this case the Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr etc) display at the top of the plot rather than at the bottom?

```
require(ggplot2)
mydf <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("1995/1/1"), by="month", length.out=203),yoy=runif(203, min=-1, max=1))
p_heat <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x=month(date,label=TRUE),y=year(date), fill = yoy, label = sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*yoy),size=10)) + 
  scale_y_date(major="years", format="%Y") +
  geom_tile() + geom_text(aes(size=10)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", high = "green") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  opts(title="Value (%)") +
  opts(panel.grid.minor=theme_blank()) +
  opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank()) +
  opts(panel.grid.major=theme_blank()) +
  opts(axis.title.y = theme_blank()) +
  opts(axis.title.x = theme_blank()) +
  opts(legend.position = "none")
p_heat
```

[image]

Comment: Please avoid red-green colour schemes, because ~10% of men will have great difficulty distinguishing positive from negative values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first two points, you can replace `scale_y_continuous` with `scale_y_reverse` to have the earliest years on top, and explicitly specify the breaks and labels.

```
p_heat +  scale_y_reverse(breaks=1995:2011, labels=1995:2011, expand=c(0,0) )
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that works for me. Useful to have somebody in the same time zone!

Comment: Incidentally, does anybody have a view on where I should put the "size" argument in this code fragment to best control the size of the font in the heatmap itself? Should it be in the ggplot statement, the geom_tile, the geom_text part or...?

Comment: The size should be outside of "aes", otherwise it is interpreted as a 1-value factor and has no effect: geom_text(size=10) should work.

Comment: Ah, setting instead of mapping, of course. Yes, it has made a difference. Much appreciated.