# How to have conditional formatting of data frames in R Shiny?

Tags: r, formatting, conditional-statements, shiny

With Excel, you can easily apply conditional formatting over cells:

[image]

Is there any chance you can do something like this with Shiny? I've gone through the [tutorials](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/), but this apparently is not covered.

For instance, I'd like to conditionally colour the `perm` row in `runExample("02_text")`:

[image]

Comment: not really Shiny-related (though I can see why it might be thought of that way) and more `ggplot`-related and a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784095/r-ggplot-heatmap-using-geom-tile-how-to-sort-by-year-and-show-all-years-in-y

Comment: For conditions having form "lower than" you can use the shinyBS package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can conditionnal formatting your table using jQuery.

For example :

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

script <- "$('tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {

              var cellValue = $(this).text();

              if (cellValue > 50) {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#0c0');
              }
              else if (cellValue <= 50) {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
              }
            })"

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode", function(message) { eval(message.value); });'))),
    tableOutput("view")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    session$onFlushed(function() {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = script))
    })

    output$view <- renderTable({
      head(rock, n = 20)
    })
  }
))
```

In `tbody tr td:nth-child(5)` I precise `nth-child(5)` To loop on each `td` of the 5th column only (perms).

We need `session$onFlushed(function() {
          session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = script))
        })` because if you put the script in the head, it will be executed before the table output rendered and then nothing will be formatting.

If you want more formatting I suggest you to create css classes and use `addClass` :

```
### In the UI :
tags$head(tags$style(
            ".greenCell {
                background-color: #0c0;
            }

            .redCell {
                background-color: #f00;
            }"))

### In th script
### use .addClass instead of .css(...)

$(this).addClass('greenCell')
```

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same thing in a more complex shiny app where the table is located within a renderUI function with no success. Is it possible that the problem might be that the contents of the table are characters? If this is so, how could you modify the script to convert the characters to numbers?

Comment: Can't you cast your characters into numbers with the `as.numeric` function ?

Comment: Maybe you can test before and format them as percentages after the test on numeric values ? Or provide an example of your app.

Comment: I am afraid that something else must be the issue. I just tried the same example you posted but replaced head(rock, n = 20) with head(rock,c(1,2),as.character), n = 20) and the table is still correctly formatted. Must be something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: `head(rock,c(1,2),as.character), n = 20)` how can this works ? ~~ I think you should create another post with your own example.

Comment: Thanks for your help and my apologies for the typo: What I meant was: head(apply(rock,c(1,2),as.character), n = 20). I understand that without an example it is hard for you help but as this is part of a big project I have to isolate a meaningful part of it and then post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62345/discussion-between-christos-and-julien-navarre).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174601/r-shiny-table-conditional-formatting-within-renderui/), which provides options for conditional formatting with cutoff points (with a [similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176474/4557776) to [Julien's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22857280/4557776)).

[Cross-posting from that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470164/4557776): To achieve conditional formatting with gradients based on cell values (for instance, to produce a heat map within a data table) you can combined the above approach with the [approach taken in this Jquery blog post](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-flexible-data-heat-map/).

Note that this example asks you to define a max and min manually, but you can also create an array of all of your values and dynamically find the min and max for your data: see [step 1 in this post](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-flexible-data-heat-map/).

Borrowing from [jdharrison's self contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176474/2246380):

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
script <- "
// Set min and max for gradient

var min = 0;
var max = 100;
var n = max-min

// Define the min colour, which is white
    xr = 255; // Red value
    xg = 255; // Green value
    xb = 255; // Blue value

// Define the max colour #2ca25f
    yr = 44; // Red value
    yg = 162; // Green value
    yb = 95; // Blue value


$('tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
var val = parseInt($(this).text());

// Catch exceptions outside of range
if (val > max) {
  var val = max;
}

else if (val < min) {
  var val = min;
}

// Find value's position relative to range

var pos = ((val-min) / (n-1));

// Generate RGB code
red = parseInt((xr + (( pos * (yr - xr)))).toFixed(0));
green = parseInt((xg + (( pos * (yg - xg)))).toFixed(0));
blue = parseInt((xb + (( pos * (yb - xb)))).toFixed(0));

clr = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';

// Apply to cell

$(this).css('background-color', clr);

})"

runApp(list(server = function(input, output, session) {
  session$onFlushed(function() {
    session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = script))
  }, FALSE)
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(rock, n = 20)
  })
  output$Test1 <- renderUI({
    list(
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode", function(message) { eval(message.value); });')))
      , tableOutput("view")
    )
  })
  }
  , ui = fluidPage(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Test1",uiOutput("Test1")),
      tabPanel("Test2")
    )
  ))
  )
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score -1):

I got cell colouring in Shiny `DataTables`, which I believe is jQuery under the hood, using this code below for the `options` part of the `renderDataTable` call:

```
options = list(fnRowCallback = I(colouring_datatables(do_colouring=do_colouring,c("regular","strict","strict","regular","strict","regular","regular","regular"),c(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))), bSortClasses = TRUE, aaSorting=list(list(3, "desc")), aLengthMenu = list(c(10, 25, 50, 100, -1), c('10', '25', '50', '100', 'All')),
      "sDom" = 'RMDT<"cvclear"C><"clear">lfrtip',
               "oTableTools" = list(
                       "sSwfPath" = "copy_csv_xls.swf",
                       "aButtons" = list(
                                 "copy",
                                 "print",
                                 list("sExtends" = "collection",
                                                     "sButtonText" = "Save",
                                                     "aButtons" = list("xls","csv")
                                                )
                               )
                     )
      )
```

I defined a list of colour ranges, like "regular", "strict", etc and had them in this colouring_datatables function below:

```
colouring_datatables = function(do_colouring = TRUE, apply_ranges,apply_columns) {
  string = ''

  callback_init = ""
  callback_ends = ""

  function_init = 'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {'
  function_ends = '}'

  # highviz
  #regular$colour = c("#FF0000","#FF3800","#FF7100","#FFAA00","#FFE200","#E2FF00","#AAFF00","#71FF00","#38FF00","#00FF00")

  # Semaphore: only three colours
  semaphore = list()
  semaphore$from   = c(0.000    ,0.500    ,0.750    )
  semaphore$to     = c(0.500    ,0.750    ,1.100    )
  semaphore$colour = c("#F7977A","#FFF79A","#82CA9D")

  # Strict: ten colours with most granularity around 0.900 and 1.000
  strict = list()
  strict$from   = c(0.000    ,0.500    ,0.800    ,0.900    ,0.960    ,0.970    ,0.975    ,0.980    ,0.985    ,0.990    )
  strict$to     = c(0.500    ,0.800    ,0.900    ,0.960    ,0.970    ,0.975    ,0.980    ,0.985    ,0.990    ,1.100    )
  strict$colour = c("#F7977A","#F3AC7B","#F0C07C","#ECD27D","#E8E27E","#D8E47F","#C3E180","#B0DD80","#9FD981","#8FD581")

  # Regular: ten colours with most granularity between 0.800 and 0.900
  regular = list()
  regular$from   = c(0.000    ,0.500    ,0.700    ,0.800    ,0.860    ,0.870    ,0.875    ,0.880    ,0.885    ,0.890    )
  regular$to     = c(0.500    ,0.700    ,0.800    ,0.860    ,0.870    ,0.875    ,0.880    ,0.885    ,0.890    ,1.100    )
  regular$colour = c("#F7977A","#F3AC7B","#F0C07C","#ECD27D","#E8E27E","#D8E47F","#C3E180","#B0DD80","#9FD981","#8FD581")

  # Linear: twenty colours with linear scale from 0.000 to 1.000
  linear = list()
  linear$from   = c(0.000    ,0.050    ,0.100    ,0.150    ,0.200    ,0.250    ,0.300    ,0.350    ,0.400    ,0.450    ,0.500    ,0.550    ,0.600    ,0.650    ,0.700    ,0.750    ,0.800    ,0.850    ,0.900    ,0.950    )
  linear$to     = c(0.050    ,0.100    ,0.150    ,0.200    ,0.250    ,0.300    ,0.350    ,0.400    ,0.450    ,0.500    ,0.550    ,0.600    ,0.650    ,0.700    ,0.750    ,0.800    ,0.850    ,0.900    ,0.950    ,1.100    )
  linear$colour = c("#F7967A","#F4A47A","#F2B17B","#EFBE7C","#EDC97C","#EBD47D","#E8DF7D","#E4E67E","#D6E47F","#C9E17F","#BCDF7F","#B1DC80","#A5DA80","#9BD880","#91D581","#87D381","#81D184","#81CE8D","#81CC95","#82CA9D")

  # Twenty: twenty colours with most granularity between 0.700 and 1.000
  twenty = list()
  twenty$from   = c(0.000    ,0.200    ,0.300    ,0.400    ,0.500    ,0.700    ,0.720    ,0.740    ,0.760    ,0.780    ,0.800    ,0.820    ,0.840    ,0.860    ,0.880    ,0.900    ,0.920    ,0.940    ,0.960    ,0.980    )
  twenty$to     = c(0.200    ,0.300    ,0.400    ,0.500    ,0.700    ,0.720    ,0.740    ,0.760    ,0.780    ,0.800    ,0.820    ,0.840    ,0.860    ,0.880    ,0.900    ,0.920    ,0.940    ,0.960    ,0.980    ,1.100    )
  twenty$colour = c("#F7967A","#F4A47A","#F2B17B","#EFBE7C","#EDC97C","#EBD47D","#E8DF7D","#E4E67E","#D6E47F","#C9E17F","#BCDF7F","#B1DC80","#A5DA80","#9BD880","#91D581","#87D381","#81D184","#81CE8D","#81CC95","#82CA9D")

  ranges = list()
  ranges[["semaphore"]]  = semaphore
  ranges[["strict"]]     = strict
  ranges[["regular"]]    = regular
  ranges[["linear"]]     = linear
  ranges[["twenty"]]     = twenty

  string = paste0(string, callback_init)
  string = paste0(string, function_init)

  if (do_colouring) {
    for (i in 1:length(apply_columns)) {
      for (idx in 1:length(ranges[[apply_ranges[i]]]$from)) {
        this = list()
        this$column = apply_columns[i]
        this$from   = ranges[[apply_ranges[i]]]$from[idx]
        this$to     = ranges[[apply_ranges[i]]]$to[idx]
        this$colour  = ranges[[apply_ranges[i]]]$colour[idx]

        string = paste0(string,'if (parseFloat(aData[',this$column,'])  >= ',this$from,' && parseFloat(aData[',this$column,'])  < ',this$to,') { $("td:eq(',this$column,')", nRow).css("background-color", "',this$colour,'"); }')
      }
    }
  }

  string = paste0(string, function_ends)
  string = paste0(string, callback_ends)

  return(string)
}
```