# CSS: Table format - borders, spacing in specific column and conditional formating

Tags: css

I am trying to format via css a paricular table as it shows in the below picture:

[image: My Table]

As I am new to css I am having problems with specifying:

1. Borders: As you can see I want to have different border colors and weights for vertical and horizontal borders; for row names and column name
2. Gap after the 13th column: One solution would possibly be to create a second table and place them next to each other but i wouldn't like to go for that solution
3. Conditional Formating: Could I do that using css or I have to go the [jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850562/how-to-have-conditional-formatting-of-data-frames-in-r-shiny)

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple actually.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

table th {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

table tr th:nth-child(4),
table tr td:nth-child(4) {
    border: none;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Conditional formatting should be handled by JS, or if the data is populated from a database, do it on the server side and use classnames on the columns.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b579hy76/

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that with `nth-child(x)` you have to add an extra empty column after the 13hn column to archieve this effect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I thought about it and I was about to ask for validation on this one.

Comment: I think theres only one hacky way to fix this without adding additional elements and an empty row: http://jsfiddle.net/b579hy76/2/ But its pretty stupid, just add an empty row instead:)