# R: color backgorund of rows in DataTable Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

I am wondering whether it is possible to use a jQuery solution `DT` R package in Shiny and create a few color backgrounds based on `ShinyTable` package?
It is possible to use 'DT' in `ShinyTable`? Or implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174601/r-shiny-table-conditional-formatting-within-renderui) to `DT`?


Or just implement condition (if column1 >50) return green backround otherwise return red one?

Comment: Please file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues if you want. Currently it is possible to do that in DT, but you have to write a bit of JavaScript. I hope this can be achieved without requiring users to write JavaScript.

Comment: @Yihui I crete new issue. Thanks. https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/31. Btw do you know how to do it using JavaScript code?

Comment: @ Yihui One more question... do you know to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257002/recreative-list-of-names-in-checkboxgroupinput-shiny I try figure it out, but not works..

Comment: The short answer is use jQuery `if (____) $(____).css('background-color', '____')` in the column render function or the rowCallback function. See http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html Sorry I have to focus on other work in the next few weeks, so I cannot fill out the blanks for you.