# R shiny: color cell background based on Lab color space

Tags: jquery, css, r, shiny, lab-color-space

I have a dataframe which contains Lab color space values. Here is an example:

```
L*     a*     b*       color
80     25     -30       NA
75     55     55        NA
30     0      25        NA
10     -20    30        NA
55     15     20        NA
60     43     18        NA
...  ...
```

Here are more than 1000 records. I would like to color the cells in the column color based on the Lab color space value in the L*,a*,b* columns. I have no background of the Jquery. I found an example here: [R Shiny: table conditional formatting within renderUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174601/r-shiny-table-conditional-formatting-within-renderui/26176474#26176474) but I do not know how to modify the Jquery script. Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you were to color by rgb color space instead:

```
library(shiny)

color.min <- 0
color.max <- 250
n <- 100

# Simulate data
random.data <- data.frame("l"=runif(n,min=color.min,max=color.max),
                          "a"=runif(n,min=color.min,max=color.max),
                          "b"=runif(n,min=color.min,max=color.max),
                          "color"=rep(NA,n))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    output$table <- renderTable({
      random.data
    })
  })
})


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Add jQuery script
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
          function color(){
            if(document.querySelector('#table')!=null){
              // Select each table row in an array and loop over that with jQuery each
              $('#table > table > tbody').find('tr').each(function(index, value) { 
                // Get values for rgb and round to integers
                var vals = [];
                $(this).children('td').slice(1, 4).each(function(index, value) { 
                  vals[index] = parseInt( $(this).html() );
                });
                // Color 5:th child the selected rgb color
                $(':nth-child(5)',this).css('background','rgb('+String(vals[0])+','+String(vals[1])+','+String(vals[2])+')');
              })
            }
            else{
              setTimeout(function() { color(); }, 100);
            }
          }
          color();
           ")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(10, uiOutput("table")),
    column(2,actionButton("color","color"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: your answer is so useful. I have additional question. Do you know how to remove that color button? So the cell background can automatically display? Many thanks to you!

Comment: Sure, just run the code when the page is loaded. I'll edit my answer to show how to do this

Comment: Okay, I had to go with a different solution but basically I'm checking every 0.1 seconds if a element with id table exists and if it does it runs the coloring part. It's not super elegant but it works.

Comment: it is an amazing answer which I am really looking for. Thank you so much. If I have further questions, I will ask you. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great! sure, just let me know

Comment: I have one more question here. I found that if I directly read the data from a excel file. The script can display the color but if I filtered data by change the L*, a*, b* value. (I set some criterias in the sidebar.) The script:observe({
    output$table <- renderTable({
      filter()
    })
  })
})can not display the cell with color. Do you think it may the Jquery's isse? Thank you!

Comment: Yes this is a jQuery issue,  it's because the script as it is right now only colors the table once. There's a couple of ways to get around this, use a shiny binding for the color function and call it every time you update the table or monitor the DOM for change in your wanted element.

Comment: Here is my understanding about your explanation. If I add the color button back, each time, after I change my criterias, I click the color button. The jQuery will color the table again. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92899/discussion-between-oskar-forsmo-and-cutebunny).