# conditionally format dynamically created table in R

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-formatting

I would like to render a table in R, with cells formatted according to some  non-trivial logic.  (e.g. if a value is odd, color the cell yellow; if it is also >5, make the text bold, etc.).  This logic would be applied to each column of a dynamically created table, i.e. the column names are unknown so cannot be used in the code.

If found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174601/r-shiny-table-conditional-formatting-within-renderui) JQuery approach helpful, but I'm not sure it completely solves my problem, plus I would prefer an R-based approach.

I also came close using the [condformat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/condformat/vignettes/introduction.html) package, but for some reason the following doesn't work:

```
library(condformat)
data(iris)

# Create a condformat object
cf <- condformat(iris)

# Add rules to it:
for (col in colnames(iris)[1:2]) {
  cf <- cf %>% rule_css(!!col, 
expression = ifelse(eval(parse(text=col)) < 3.3, "red", "black"),
css_field = 'color')
}
# Render it
cf
```

The first column of the resulting table doesn’t abide by the rule; instead, it is given the colors from column 2.  But if I instead loop over just that first column, the coloring for it is correct.

Any help with the above code, or with the problem generally, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`kableExtra` is a very powerful tool for creating HTML tables in R.

```
library(kableExtra)

iris[1:10, 1:2] %>% 
  mutate(
    Sepal.Length = cell_spec(
      Sepal.Length, 
      "html", 
      background = ifelse(Sepal.Length %% 2 == 1, "yellow", "red"),
      bold = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, T, F)
    ),
    Sepal.Width = cell_spec(
      Sepal.Width, 
      "html", 
      background = ifelse(Sepal.Width %% 2 == 1, "blue", "green"),
      bold = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 10, T, F)
    ),
  )  %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```

Please refer to the documentation for additional details:
[Create Awesome HTML Table with knitr::kable and kableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the helpful package, but this too fails to address the "dynamically created table" part.  (I realize my code snippet doesn't either, I was trying to keep things tractable).  Is there a way to add the cell_spec() logic to e.g. all numeric columns of a table?  I'd like to use this in a Shiny app that doesn't know the dimensions & column names of the table beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically created table" ? I always create my tables using `kableExtra` in Shiny and they are dynamical. Just wrap this code inside a reactive expression to make it dynamic and interactive.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this on a dynamic table, you could loop over the columns of the data.frame like this (taking most of the code from Ozan147's answer):

```
library(kableExtra)

test <- iris[1:10, ]


for(i in 1:ncol(test)){

  if(is.numeric(test[[i]])){
      test[[i]] <- cell_spec(
                      test[[i]], 
                     "html", 
                      background = ifelse(test[[i]] %% 2 == 1, "yellow", "red"),
                      bold = ifelse(test[[i]] > 5, T, F)
                     )
  }
}

test %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```