# How to add conditional formatting to shiny tables in R?

Tags: r, shiny

Code details mentioned below.

```
**server.R**
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  getTable <- reactive({
    // Some manipulations done every 2 mins and table is updated
    // Assume tbl_op has only one row with 3 columns
    // The table values represent time in hh:mm:ss
    tbl_op
  })

  output$tableUI <- renderTable({
    getTable()
  },include.rownames=FALSE)  
})

**ui.R**
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(    
    fluidRow(      
      column(width = 5, offset = 1,             
             tableOutput("tableUI")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I am able to display the output in the required format, however I am not able to add formatting to it.

I want the table cell values to be highlighted in red when the time difference(absolute value of difference between System Time and the value displayed in the table cell) is more than 2 min. The table is updated every two minutes. The cell value should be highlighted whenever the difference is more than 2 min.

If it is possible with Datatable, then please provide the code.

Comment: It's possible to apply conditional formatting to data tables displayed in Shiny but it's rather involved exercise, did you have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22850562/1655567)? If i can take the liberty of making another suggestion, why don't you repost your code as a single `app.R` file with some dummy data? It would be easier to for folk to work with, I wanted to have a look at this but lost interest as it looks like a lot of work with as all the data and transformations would have to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

There is two task :

## Format DT cells

it can be done using `formatStyle(`

## Update every 2 mins

it can be done using `reactiveTimer`

Try something like :

UI

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

  shinyUI(

      fluidRow(      

        DT::dataTableOutput("tableUI")

      )
    )
  )
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


tbl_op=data.frame(z=as.POSIXct(Sys.time())+1:10 )


shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  ttt=reactiveValues(tbl_op=tbl_op)

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(2000, session)

  observe({
  autoInvalidate()
 print(Sys.time())
 ttt$tbl_op$check=ifelse(Sys.time()> ttt$tbl_op$z,1,0)
})

    output$tableUI <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable( ttt$tbl_op,rownames=F,
                      options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE,targets=1))))%>%formatStyle("check",target = 'row',backgroundColor = styleInterval(0.5,c("red","none")))
    })  
  })
```

## PS

I update every 2 seconds and compare value in cells with current time ( for test simplisity)